# "Best"—adverb or adjective (in the sentence)

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, adverbs, syntax

The medicine is best taken after meals.

I think it's an adverb modifying verb, but it can be an adjective after the copula.

Comment: Yes, an adverb modifying the verb phrase "taken after meals".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Best* is an adverb here, as [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/best) explains:

> 2 best
> /ˈbɛst/
> **adverb**
> superlative form of 1well
> 1
> : in the best way : in a way that is better than all others

> The sauce is *best* served/eaten/enjoyed cold.